# Chome timeline - adding child causes extra layout / reflow events

Tags: google-chrome, layout, paint, timeline, reflow

I'm currently working on a website, which has a page with 2 big images (combined around 9000px) in them. The idea is that people can click and drag, to see the sides of the image, just like google maps.

At first I built it with just the 2 images next to each other. When animating the parent div on drag, I managed to only get a composite paint once in a while, but no actual paint (draws). I did this by editing the `translate3d` on the mouse events.

This all worked like a charm and very smooth, until I added an extra div to the parent. Now when I change the translate3d, it has to do a complete `recalculate style` -> `layout` -> `paint` -> `composite layers`.

So at first the structure was:

```
<div class="container" style="transform: translate3d(-50%)">
    <img src="path/to/img.jpg"><img src="path/to/img.jpg">
</div>
```

When changing the `translate3d`, all was good, just had a `Composite Layers` once in a while.

However, when I change it to the following, all goes bananas:

```
<div class="container" style="transform: translate3d(-50%)">
    <img src="path/to/img.jpg"><img src="path/to/img.jpg">
    <div>+</div>
</div>
```

So like said before, now when editing `translate3d`, it has to do a complete `Recalculate style`.

I made sure the div and images both had layers by adding `translateZ(0)` on them, that didn't help though :(

I'm pretty sure I don't understand the whole paint sequence of chrome to the detail, but after countless hours of reading I can't find the exact thing. I hope someone can shed some light on this matter.

Thanks a bunch!

Edit after Paul's reply:

The `Recalculate Style` is triggered by the following line:

```
this.background.style.transform = 'translate3d(' + (this.panoramaX - this.previewOffset) + '%, 0, 0)';
```

Comment: It's a hunch, but I suspect the layout is due to Blink trying to determine if there's a need for scroll bars. Can you add `overflow: hidden` to the parent of `container`?

Comment: @PaulLewis thanks for the reply! Unfortunately it didn't fix the layout though :(

In the timeline I can see the following code is responsible for the whole `Recalculate style` (Will edit in original question)

Comment: If that's the case, put `will-change:transform` on the element by default. This will make sure it's always a layer regardless of the translate3d being applied.

Comment: Too bad that didn't fix the problem @PaulIrish, before that I also tried forcing the layer with a translateZ(0). I'm kinda at a loss for now, will continue building the rest and try to fix it later. When I figure something out I will let you guys know!

Comment: Any chance you can pop a test case on a URL somewhere. I'd like to take a look over it.